# Unable to Knit HTML /PDF/Word in R Studio(Version 0.98.1103). Encountering "Execution Halted"

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

1. I was working on R markdown documents in R studio, and I had knit the HTML, PDF and Word. It had worked fine.
2. Then when I tried to publish it online I encountered an error 
   " Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate Calls: rpubsUpload ...  -> .postForm -> .Call ->  -> fun Execution halted"

To solve which I had found a solution at " https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205002917-SSL-certificate-problem-when-publishing-to-RPubs" which suggested running the command
file.edit('~/.Rprofile') within RStudio 
and inserting the following code:
options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal" .

But after doing the above, I have not been able to knit any thing in R Studio. 
Every time I click Knit button I keep encountering

"Error: could not find function "file.edit"
Execution halted"

How can I resolve this and get things to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the solution. I simply found where my .Rprofile was and deleted it. It solved my problem.